# How can I access to Flexform Settings when I embed my plugin over TypoScript

Tags: typo3, extbase

I embed a TYPO3 plugin via typoscript and everything is ok. I can access to the TypoScript Settings but not to Flexform Settings. here is my code:

```
temp.mCOA = USER
temp.mCOA {
  userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
  extensionName = ExtensionName
  pluginName = Pi1
  vendorName = Vendor
  controller = MyController
  action = list
  switchableControllerActions {
    MyController {
        1 = list
    }
  }
  view < plugin.tx_extensionname_pi1.view
  persistence < plugin.tx_extensionname_pi1.persistence
  settings < plugin.tx_extensionname_pi1.settings
}
```

Can Someone help me Please?
thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 6):

If you set your extension within typoscript there is no FlexForm. The FlexForm belongs to an Content Element.

Settings to the typoscript embeded version must be put into the `plugin.tx_extensionname_pi1.settings` scope per TypoScript.

With Flexform you can provide the abilty to your users to override typoscript settings when they put an new content element with your plugin onto an page.

Comment: Please accept an answer if it helped you, so other can see that this question was successfully answered.